# Troubles with setting object in VBA

Tags: vba, object, hyperlink

Maybe this question is simple, but I couldn't find an answer by googling.

So, I've got my class WSheet. I initialize array of objects of this class in my program:

```
    ReDim WSheets(twb.Sheets.Count)
For i = 0 To UBound(WSheets)
    Set WSheets(i) = New WSheet
Next i
```

And then, I try to read new values and sort them by insertion sort:

```
For i = twb.Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1
    flag = False
    tsName = twb.Sheets(i).Name
    twb.Sheets(i).Delete
    twb.Save
    CurShW = curLen - FileLen(TempFName)
    curLen = FileLen(TempFName)
    For j = UBound(WSheets) To 2 Step -1
        If WSheets(j - 1).Weight < CurShW Then
            Set WSheets(j) = WSheets(j - 1)
        Else
            WSheets(j).SetName (tsName)
            WSheets(j).SetWeight (CurShW)
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If Not flag Then 
        Set WSheets(1) = New WSheet
        WSheets(1).SetName (tsName)
        WSheets(1).SetWeight (CurShW)
        flag = False
    End If
Next i
```

So, the problem: after I set WSheets(j) = WSheets(j - 1), wsheets(j - 1) starts to contain link to wsheets(j), so, when I change wsheets(j), Wsheets (j - 1) changes too.

Please, share how to make absolute equation in this sample?

Thank you!

PS code in WSheet class

```
Dim SName As String 'Name of sheet
Dim SWeight As Long 'Weight of sheet in bytes
Dim blocks() As Long 'Weights of blocks in sheet in bytes

Public Function Weight() As Long
    Weight = SWeight
End Function

Public Sub SetWeight(ByVal sw As Long)
    SWeight = sw
End Sub

Public Function Name() As String
    Name = SName
End Function

Public Sub SetName(ByVal nm As String)
    SName = nm
End Sub
```

Comment: upload the code in your `WSheet` Class, it will allow us (or me) to try and trace the phenomena

Comment: Added in PS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** to turn the function into a `Class` method

You must *clone* the `WSheet` object instead of referencing it

For instance you could add a `Clone()` method to your `WSheet` class

```
Function Clone() As WSheet
    Dim newWSheet As WSheet

    Set newWSheet = New WSheet
    newWSheet.SetName SName
    newWSheet.SetWeight SWeight
    Set Clone = newWSheet
End Function
```

Then in your main code change:

```
Set WSheets(j) = WSheets(j - 1)
```

To:

```
Set WSheets(j) = WSheets(j - 1).Clone
```

Comment: @PG_Develop, did you get through it?

Comment: Yes, I did the similar thing myself. When I was asking question, I expected to learn some built-in way to "clone" objects..

Comment: But your solution works and nobody suggested a better way to do it. So, lets assume, that there is no such built-in way in VBA, and I will mark your answer as solution. Thanks a lot, user!